# How to remove flicking in IE?

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have created [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/E49Q4/1/) where I have flicking problem in IE. Even Chrome isnt good, but in fiddle it looks more or less fine. I think problem is in "size of step" for one scroll, when you grab scroller manualy everything is smooth, but using your mousewheel leads to jumping/flicking in IE and Chrome.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { ...}, false);
```

This is my current HTML:

```
<div id="fakeBody">
    <div id="spacer">scroll down</div>
    <div class="niceBanner hide roller" id="niceBannerFrame">
        <div id="bannerShadow"></div>
        <div id="thumb0">
            <div id="niceBannerOriginal" class="roller thumb1 thumb2"></div>
            <div id="niceBannerBlur" class="roller deblur thumb1 thumb2"></div>
            <div id="blackRow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {

    var totalHeigth, currentScroll, visibleHeight;
    var newResolutionBannerHeight = 0;
    currentScroll = (document.documentElement.scrollTop) ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;

    totalHeigth = (document.height !== undefined) ? document.height : document.getElementById("fakeBody").offsetHeight;
    visibleHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    var w = window,
        d = document,
        e = d.documentElement,
        g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
        y = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight;


    var curentWidth = x;
    console.log('curent Width: ' + curentWidth);

    if (curentWidth < 1070) {
        var newBannerWidth = Math.round((curentWidth / 1070) * 1920);

        var newMargin = Math.round((newBannerWidth - curentWidth) / 2);

        newResolutionBannerHeight = Math.round((500 / 1920) * newBannerWidth);

    } else {}

    //now it is easy to recognize if visitor is at the bottom of page
    if (visibleHeight + currentScroll >= totalHeigth) {
        //do the magic with banner
        document.getElementById("niceBannerFrame").className = "unhide";

        var bannerHeight = visibleHeight + currentScroll - totalHeigth;
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.type = 'text/css';
        var number = (curentWidth < 500) ? 10 + bannerHeight : 50 + bannerHeight; //not ideal solution, slower rolling for small screen, picture is realy small

        if (curentWidth > 1070) {
            number = (number > 500) ? 500 : number;
            var opacityBlur = 1 - (number / 500);
            style.innerHTML = '.roller {bottom:-' + number + 'px;} .deblur {opacity:' + opacityBlur + ';} .thumb2{height: 500px;} ';
        } else {
            number = (number > newResolutionBannerHeight) ? newResolutionBannerHeight : number;
            var opacityBlur = 1 - (number / newResolutionBannerHeight);
            style.innerHTML = '.roller {bottom:-' + number + 'px;} .deblur {opacity:' + opacityBlur + ';} .thumb2{height:' + newResolutionBannerHeight + 'px;} ';
        }
        document.head.appendChild(style);
    } else {
        //it is not good time for magic, scroll a bit more or I will hide already visible bilboard
        document.getElementById("niceBannerFrame").className = "hide";
    }
}, false);
```

and CSS:

```
#spacer {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
#niceBannerOriginal {
    background-image:url(http://nzworker.com/jakub-portfolio/justfiles/1920x500_original.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    z-index:-3;
}
#niceBannerBlur {
    background-image:url(http://nzworker.com/jakub-portfolio/justfiles/1920x500_blur.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    z-index:-2;
}
#bannerShadow {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(http://nzworker.com/jakub-portfolio/justfiles/Stin.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-1;
    height:25px;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
.unhide {
    display: block;
}
#fakeBody {
    height:1000px;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
#blackRow {
    display:none;
}
#niceBannerFrame {
    overflow: hidden;
}
@media (min-width: 1921px) {
    #blackRow {
        background-color: #000000;
        display: block;
        height:500px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -6;
    }
}
/*desktop resolution*/
 @media (min-width: 1070px) and (max-width: 1920px) {
    .thumb1 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        /*image centering*/
    }
    .thumb2 {
    }
}
/*mobile and tablet resolution*/
 @media (max-width: 1069px) {
    .thumb2 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        /*background-position: 50% 50%; image centering*/
    }
    #niceBannerOriginal {
        background-image:url(http://nzworker.com/jakub-portfolio/justfiles/1920x500_original-thumb.jpg);
        background-size: 100%;
    }
    #niceBannerBlur {
        background-image:url(http://nzworker.com/jakub-portfolio/justfiles/1920x500_blur-thumb.jpg);
        background-size: 100%;
    }
}
```

My question is do you how to remove this flicking? Or do you know how to cut one mouse wheel step to more smaller ones?

PS: I can not use jQuery or other plugins.

Comment: Is what you are trying to do a sticky footer? In which case there are are several existing solutions that don't even use javascript. (I'm pretty sure this is one that I've used before http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/ ). What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you have any examples on the web of it working properly?

Comment: No I am not trying to create sticky footer. my goal to create "unhiding" banner, like a "sunblind" or "textil shader". but thanks for an idea, I will try combine my solution with sticky footer. There is no web which I know with this effect.

Comment: Answer below. A bit too long to put as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be 100% sure about this, but I think the flickering isn't from the amount you're scrolling, but due to the fact that you're changing the display mode, and pushing the view back up a tiny bit.

Essentially if you are just underneath the `visibleHeight+currentScroll >= totalHeigth` test by a couple of pixels, then `currentScroll` get's pushed up a tiny bit when whatever happens in there happens (I don't entirely understand what's going on, so I can't really give any better advice on that), so that it's no longer greater than `totalHigth`, and so it then fails the test immediately after, hence the flickering.

Worked this out by getting rid of the `hide` line at the end and it seems to work. Unfortunately I don't entirely understand the code, so I can't give you any better idea than that, though hopefully it points you towards a solution.

Comment: Hi thanks for an answer. You are right about removing .hide, but that is not a big problem. My problem is "not smooth" or "chopped" move during rolling mouse wheel. If I use sidebar for manual scrollliing it works fine. As I have said for FF it works, for rest it is not 8(

Comment: Sorry, I actually see what you're actually trying to do. I was trying it in Safari where all I got was the tiniest line down the bottom. I didn't even realise it was a car ad. In terms of the jagged scrolling, there isn't any for me when I try in chrome. It might be that your computer isn't handling it. Otherwise I don't think it's a problem with your code.

Comment: I have try it on 2 computers and effect is everywhere same. I would be surprised if it works fine for you. But thank you for your time with my problem.